# How to change class uk-width-1-3 to uk-width-1-1

Tags: joomla-3.x, zoo

Any idea why joomla dont change the class
uk-width-1-3 in desktop to
uk-width-1-1 in smartphone?

This should be automacally?
https://www.feltrosrenner.com.br/index.php/produtos

[image: View in desktop]

[image: View in smartphone]

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem change from UlKit3 to Ulkit in config area.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using uikit, whose instructions to creating a grid layout are [here](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/grid.html).  The *Responsive width* section is the bit you need to look at.

Basically, `uk-width-1-3` applies to all screen widths, `uk-width-small-1-3` would apply to devices over 470px only, and below that width would stack the elements in a single column, which sounds like what you are wanting to do.

Comment: But in this case I need change "uk-width-1-3" to "uk-width-1-1" if with less 480px. I think this should bu automatically. I miss some JS ?